# What is the origin of "all work and no play makes Jack a dull boy"?

Tags: the-shining

In the movie *The Shining*, there is a whole stack of papers reading "all work and no play makes Jack a dull boy" on the desk next to the typewriter.

Where does this phrase come from? Does it come from folklore, or a bedtime story?

Comment: you could've just googled that...

Comment: Being Googleable doesn't in itself make it a bad question. This crops up many times over SE & ultimately Googleable does not make it bad to ask.

Comment: LMGTFY (Let me google that for you) comments are generally frowned upon over SE as "not nice", although there's always debate over it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_work_and_no_play_makes_Jack_a_dull_boy):

> "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy" is a proverb. It means
>   that without time off from work, a person becomes both bored and
>   boring. The exact origins of the phrase remain unclear, though it was
>   recorded as early as 1659.